# Cannot convert value of type '() -> ()' to expected argument type 'Selector'

Tags: swift4

I encountered this error when I used the selector.

I am using xcode9.0 swift4.

[image]

**Error**

[image]

Any suggestion will be appreciated

Comment: Please post text, not screenshots. You don't use *selector*.

Answer (score 0):

Use `#selector(onTimer)` instead of `onTimer` in selector and write `@objc` before method declaration i.e. `@objc func onTimer()`